# Powershell Workflow Sequence

Tags: powershell, workflow

I have written the following script which picks a list of servers from a text file and does Ping,RDP,Remote Registry and WMI checks. I am using hash table for getting the results. I am outputting the results to the console and a text file as well. What I have observed is the execution of the script takes more than ~15 minutes for ~20 servers to perform the 4 checks. I read about the Powershell Workflow concept and executing the checks in parallel to multiple servers. I need some help with my script please in how I can use the workflow and foreach -parallel

```
workflow ftccheck
{
param($servers)

#Text file to pick the server names
$servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\serverlist.txt"

#Format DateTime to String
$datetime = Get-Date
$datestring = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")

#Create the output files
$offlinefile = "offline_$datestring.txt"
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\temp -Name $offlinefile

$onlinefile = "online_$datestring.txt"
New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\temp -Name $onlinefile

#Write Date and Time to the output files at each iteration
Write-Output $datetime | Out-File C:\temp\$offlinefile -Append
Write-Output $datetime | Out-File C:\temp\$onlinefile -Append

$offcount = 0
$oncount = 0

foreach -parallel ($server in $servers)
{
InlineScript
{
    Write-Host `r
    Write-Host $server
    Write-Host `r

    #PING
    $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet -Count 1

    #RDP
    $rdp  = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -CommonTCPPort RDP -InformationLevel Quiet

    #REMOTE REGISTRY
    $regkey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$server)
    $ref = $regkey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

    #WMI
    $wmi  = GWMI -Query "Select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'"

#Create hashtables
$state_noun = @{
   $true  = 'SUCCESS'
   $false = 'FAIL'
 }

$state_verb = @{
   $true  = 'SUCCEEDED'
   $false = 'FAILED'
 }

#Pass results to the hashtable array
$result = @"
PING             :    $($state_noun[$ping])
RDP              :    $($state_noun[$rdp])
Remote Registry  :    $($state_noun[[bool]$ref])
WMI              :    $($state_noun[[bool]$wmi])
"@

If($result.Contains('FAIL')) { 

  Write-Output $server | Out-File C:\temp\$offlinefile -Append
  Write-Output $result | Out-File C:\temp\$offlinefile -Append
  $offcount++          
} 

elseif($result.Contains('SUCCESS')) { 

  Write-Output $server | Out-File C:\temp\$onlinefile -Append
  Write-Output $result | Out-File C:\temp\$onlinefile -Append
  $oncount++  
}

#Write the output on console
Write-Host $result

Write-Host `r
Write-Host $offcount " servers are DOWN"
Write-Host $oncount " servers are UP"

Write-Output $offcount "servers are DOWN" | Out-File C:\temp\$offlinefile -Append
#Write-Output " servers are DOWN" | Out-File C:\temp\$offlinefile -Append

Write-Output $oncount "servers are UP" | Out-File C:\temp\$onlinefile -Append   
#Write-Output " servers are UP" | Out-File C:\temp\$onlinefile -Append   

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? Your question isn't clear - you need more than "help me with X" - explain why you're having trouble with X.

Comment: @alroc, Sorry if my question was not clear. The workflow is not working and no output is returned when I execute the script with workflow. I need help in getting the script executed inside a workflow.